# Prove that a $2\times2$ real matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\vert \lambda \vert = r(A)= \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a  $2 \times 2$  real matrix and set

$$ r(A)= \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$$

where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm. I would like to prove $A$ always has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\vert \lambda \vert = r(A)$.

I know that $\ Ax =\lambda x$, so I think $\max_{x \ne 0} \Vert Ax \Vert / \Vert x \Vert = \max\vert \lambda \vert$.

Am I right? How does one prove this?

Comment: Prove what? (The title makes no sense.)

Comment: I edited your title to make it a little more clear.

Comment: I also edited the text of your question to make it more clear as well.

Comment: You would need to assume $A$ is symmetric and therefore orthogonally diagonalizable: then $\lVert A(c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_n x_n) \rVert^2 = \lambda_1^2 c_1^2 + \cdots \lambda_n^2 c_n^2 \le \max (\lambda_i^2) (c_1^2 + \cdots + c_n^2)$ from which you could conclude the proof.  (Or a similar argument should work if $A$ is normal, and you consider complex eigenvalues as well.  But there are plenty of counterexamples if $A$ is not normal, even for diagonalizable matrices.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $A$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: No eigenvalues in $\Bbb R$.  $A$ clearly has eigenvalues $\pm i  \in \Bbb C$, the zeroes of its characteristic polynomial $x^2 + 1$.  The OP's question admits this possibility by only placing conditions on $\vert r \vert$, not $r$ itself.

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, but since the OP wrote that the matrix is real, I assumed that he was interested only in real eigenvalues. Otherwise, why restrict the question to real matrices?

Comment: I won't speak to the OP's motive, but I do know that real matrices can have complex eigenvalues.  So I'm going with what I discern to be joe's stated intention.  Cheers!

Comment: Of course to address the issue of a complex eigenvalue we must also address the fact that the eigenvector will be complex as well, so we must extend the domain of $A$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb C^2$!

Answer (score 1):

$r(A)$ is the operator norm of $A$, which can be rewritten as the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ (note that $A^\top A$ is real and positive semi-definite, and thus has real nonnegative eigenvalues).

If $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, then $A^\top A =\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $r(A)^2 = (3+\sqrt{5})/2$.
However, the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$.

Comment: You can even find plenty of counterexamples where $A$ is diagonalizable: e.g. if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ it obviously has eigenvalues 2 and 1; but $A e_1 = (2, 1)$ so $r(A) \ge \sqrt{5}$.