# principal eigenvalue in infinite dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

For $A$ a symmetric, positive let $\lambda_1$ be its principal eigenvector. I want to show that
$$\lambda_1=max_{v\neq 0}\frac{<Av,v>}{||v||^2}$$

I found this link: [Prove that a $2\times2$ real matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\vert \lambda \vert = r(A)= \max_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401679/prove-that-a-2-times2-real-matrix-has-an-eigenvalue-lambda-with-vert-lam?rq=1)

one of the comments shows how to do this in finite dimensions but what does the proof look like in infinite dimension (Hilbert Space)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little involved, here are the steps, for special classes of bounded linear operators $T$ on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space:

- prove that, for compact operators, the spectrum is $\{0\}\cup \{$ eigenvalues $\}$ (eigenvalues need not to exist)
- if the ground field are the complex numbers, Gelfand's theorem ensures that the spectral radius $r(T)$ of $T$ is the biggest (in absolute value) number contained in the spectrum of $T$. Now, for normal operators, the spectral radius is just the norm, and if that operator is nonzero, you obtain that for compact normal operators the biggest eigenvalue (in absolute value), is exactly $||T||=\sup_x ||Tx||/||x|| $
- if the ground field are the reals, you need the operator to be compact and symmetric in order to show the existence of an eigenvalue whose absolute value is the norm of the operator. The eigenvalue in question is $\lim_n (Tx_n,x_n)$, where that sequence is chosen in such a way that its absolute value converges to $||T||$

Long story short, your proposition holds, for instance, for compact normal operators (on the complex numbers), and for compact symmetric operators on the reals.

Do you want further details?

Comment: sure, I'd really appreciate it if you have the time.